# SQL query to get data in a table that starts with some specific row for ios app

Tags: mysql, ios, sql, sqlite

I am having an app in which I am getting some data from my sqlite database.

Below is my query which I am using to get data from sqlite database.

```
select * from tbl where ListId = 5
```

[image: Data which I get]

I want to update this table in such a way that I want the first row of a table with some specific `WordID` that I have passed.

If I pass `WordId = 58` then first row of the table should start with this `WordID`, then rest data should be in any sequence.

How to achieve this via any sqlite query?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
select * from tbl where ListId = 5 order by WordId <> 58
```

Comment: Thanks you so much guyz for your help. Saved a lot of time for me.

Answer (score 1):

So you want first the row with `WordId = 58`, then all other rows.
This can be done by doing two queries, and then combining them:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ListId = 5 AND WordId = 58
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ListId = 5 AND WordId != 58
```

Alternatively (and if you want to sort the rows anyway), sort all the rows by an expression that orders this word first.
(The expression `WordId != 58` has a boolean result, either `0` or `1`.)

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE ListId = 5
ORDER BY WordId != 58,
         Word           -- optional; or any other column(s)
```

Comment: Thanks you so much guyz for your help. Saved a lot of time for me.